# IntelliJ copyright at compile time

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, compile-time, system-properties, copyright-display

I'm working on a build script that will generate new files for my project at compile time. These files will be shared publicly so they need to include the correct copyright information. Is there any way to reference the copyright profile from IntelliJ to the build script?

Specifically I'm using Gradle so it would be nice to call something like the following:

```
def codeHeader = <reference to IntelliJ copyright here>
writeCopyrightToFile(codeHeader)
```

If that doesn't work then is it possible to define the copyright as a system property that I could use when defining the copyright profile as well as in the script?

The underlying goal is to have the copyright defined in one location.

Answer (score 0):

The copyright is stored in a file under the project file tree. Please look into the folder `.idea/copyright/` There you will find the copyright xml files for reference.

Comment: This is certainly useful to know but do you know a good way to reference this information in the build script without parsing the xml data myself? Ideally some sort of shorthand. Something like "${idea.copyright}" or similar?